# Covariance and Overloading in Java

Tags: java, overloading, covariance

```
class A {
   boolean f(A a) { return true; }
}
class B extends A {
   boolean f(A a) { return false; } // override A.f(A)
   boolean f(B b) { return true; }  // overload A.f
}

void f() {  
   A a = new A();
   A ab = new B();
   B b = new B();
   ab.f(a); ab.f(ab); ab.f(b); //(1) false, false, *false*
   b.f(a); b.f(ab); b.f(b);    //(2) false, false, true
}
```

Can you please explain the first line last false output, why it is not true?

Comment: I don't understand why people bother to post an answer that's so short and not so explanatory as @JonSkeet's post.

Comment: I had a similar question some time back, maybe this helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883414/is-there-any-reason-that-java-uses-late-static-binding-for-overloaded-methods-in

Comment: increase your acceptence percentage please

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> can you please explain the first line last false output, why it is not true?

The compile-time type of `ab` is `A`, so the compiler - which is what performs overload resolution - determines that the only valid method signature is `f(A a)`, so it calls that.

At *execution* time, that method signature is executed as `B.f(A a)` because `B` overrides it.

Always remember that the *signature* is chosen at compile time (overloading) but the *implementation* is chosen at execution time (overriding).

Comment: As soon as saw your answer, even without reading yours i deleted mine :)..No chance that your answer would not be best :).

Comment: after seeing your answer, we cannt stop up voting it :)

Comment: Can you please explain b.f (ab); ?

Comment: @nabil: That calls `B.f(A a)` because the compile-time type of `ab` is `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Well..because you are calling on type of A. So you can call only version of f(A a). that's returning false in B.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the object type of A,  you can call only f(A A). Because B overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

> can you please explain the first line last false output, why it is not true?

Think otherwise :-

try commenting below in class B (the overriding code)

```
boolean f(A a) { return false; } // override A.f(A)
```

and add syso in Class A in this method --> `boolean f(A a){....}`

Then you'll see, `ab.f(A a)` or `ab.f(B b)` will invoke `f(A a)` method of class A only.

> As ab is of type A.

Also please note - You'll not be able to call any method of class B as well from object ab.

Hope this further adds more clarification to above brilliant answers.

Lastly, you may seek this now --> [Why do we assign a parent reference to the child object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159601/why-do-we-assign-a-parent-reference-to-the-child-object-in-java)