# Why do we assign a parent reference to the child object in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting, upcasting

I am asking a quite simple question, but I am bit confused in this.

Suppose I have a class `Parent`:

```
public class Parent {

    int name;
}
```

And have another class `Child`:

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    int salary;
}
```

And finally my Main.java class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.name= "abcd";
    }
}
```

If I make a child object like

```
Child child = new Child():
```

Then `child` object can access both `name and salary` variables.

My question is:

```
Parent parent = new Child();
```

gives the access of only `name` variable of Parent class.
So what is the exact use of this line??

```
 Parent parent = new Child();
```

And also when it is using dynamic polymorphism then why the variable of child class is not accessible after doing this

```
Parent parent = new Child();
```

Comment: Have a read of the animal example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Comment: In your example it doesn't really help. But think that you have a method that does something with a Parent reference. Somewhere in the Main class, for instance. It takes a parent object reference and does stuff with it. It would make sense to also accept sub-classes of Parent, like a Child object, even though it only does parent-stuff to it. Moreover, look into [dynamic binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321864/java-dynamic-binding-and-method-overriding) for more interesting stuff.

Comment: Is this the `name` correct type?

Comment: Just to add; In real life the children inherits features from their parents. So in the same way, here child class has every knowledge of its parent class. Of course the fields should be visible to be accessible. When you override a method, you are probably improving your Parent's `Car`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

First, a clarification of terminology: we are assigning a `Child` object to a variable of type `Parent`. `Parent` is a reference to an object that happens to be a subtype of `Parent`, a `Child`.

It is only useful in a more complicated example. Imagine you add `getEmployeeDetails` to the class Parent:

```
public String getEmployeeDetails() {
    return "Name: " + name;
}
```

We could override that method in `Child` to provide more details:

```
@Override
public String getEmployeeDetails() {
    return "Name: " + name + " Salary: " + salary;
}
```

Now you can write one line of code that gets whatever details are available, whether the object is a `Parent` or `Child`:

```
parent.getEmployeeDetails();
```

The following code:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.name = 1;
Child child = new Child();
child.name = 2;
child.salary = 2000;
Parent[] employees = new Parent[] { parent, child };
for (Parent employee : employees) {
    employee.getEmployeeDetails();
}
```

Will result in the output:

```
Name: 1
Name: 2 Salary: 2000
```

We used a `Child` as a `Parent`. It had specialized behavior unique to the `Child` class, but when we called `getEmployeeDetails()` we could ignore the difference and focus on how `Parent` and `Child` are similar. This is called [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism).

Your updated question asks why `Child.salary` is not accessible when the `Child`object is stored in a `Parent` reference. The answer is the intersection of "polymorphism" and "static typing". Because Java is statically typed at compile time you get certain guarantees from the compiler but you are forced to follow rules in exchange or the code won't compile. Here, the relevant guarantee is that every instance of a subtype (e.g. `Child`) can be used as an instance of its supertype (e.g. `Parent`). For instance, you are guaranteed that when you access `employee.getEmployeeDetails` or `employee.name` the method or field is defined on any non-null object that could be assigned to a variable `employee` of type `Parent`. To make this guarantee,  the compiler considers only that static type (basically, the type of the variable reference, `Parent`) when deciding what you can access. So you cannot access any members that are defined on the runtime type of the object, `Child`.

When you truly want to use a `Child` as a `Parent` this is an easy restriction to live with and your code will be usable for `Parent` and all its subtypes. When that is not acceptable, make the type of the reference `Child`.

Answer (score 34):

When you compile your program the reference variable of the base class gets memory and compiler checks all the methods in that class. So it checks all the base class methods but not the child class methods. Now at runtime when the object is created, only checked methods can run. 
In case a method is overridden in the child class that function runs. Child class other functions aren't run because the compiler hasn't recognized them at the compile time.

Comment: This answer makes sense! Thanks

Comment: only checked method run, means?

Comment: @Vaibhav_Sharma Checked here means which compiler recognized at compile time.

Answer (score 17):

If you assign parent type to a subclass it means that you agree with to use the common features of the parent class.

It gives you the freedom to abstract from different subclass implementations. As a result limits you with the parent features.

However, this type of assignment is called upcasting.

```
Parent parent = new Child();
```

The opposite is downcasting.

```
Child child = (Child)parent;
```

So, if you create instance of `Child` and downcast it to `Parent` you can use that type attribute `name`. If you create instance of `Parent` you can do the same as with previous case but you can't use `salary` because there's not such attribute in the `Parent`. Return to the previous case that can use `salary` but only if downcasting to `Child`.

[There's more detail explanation](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50451-upcasting-downcasting)

Comment: So for that I can do Parent parent = new Parent(). Why to do that? Plz help me out.

Comment: True, but still doesn't explain why you would want to.

Comment: Why to do it depends on what do you want to do.

Comment: If you assign `Parent` you can use `Parent` if you assign (if you can) `Child` you can use `Child`.

Comment: @JohnWatts I dont understand the concept here. If we make the child object then we can access the child class variables along with parent. and if we want to access the parent class variable then we can do it with making the parent object. So why this access is there. If you can explain me with an example then i really appriciate you

Comment: Child objects has always access to the accessible features of the parent classes because parent features belong to children and accessible if they have accessible accessors.

Comment: Child child = (Child)parent; this will result into ClassCastException. You can't downcast a parent object to a child reference variable.

Answer (score 16):

It allows you to access all subclasses through a common parent interface. This is beneficial for running common operations available on all subclasses. A better example is needed:

```
public class Shape
{
  private int x, y;
  public void draw();
}

public class Rectangle extends Shape
{ 
  public void draw();
  public void doRectangleAction();
}
```

Now if you have:

```
List<Shape> myShapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
```

You can reference every item in the list as a Shape, you don't have to worry if it is a Rectangle or some other type like let's say Circle. You can treat them all the same; you can draw all of them. You can't call doRectangleAction because you don't know if the Shape is really a rectangle.

This is a trade of you make between treating objects in a generic fashion and treating the specifically.

Really I think you need to read more about OOP. A good book should help: [http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Explained-Perspective-Object-Oriented/dp/0201715945](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201715945)

Comment: In your example quoted, are you using "abstract class" or "interface"? Because a simple class can't have unimplemented methods.

Comment: @HQuser  - well spotted, seems like wants to explain more on polymorphism in the context of question but surely this needs amendment.

Answer (score 11):

It's simple.

```
Parent parent = new Child();
```

In this case the type of the object is `Parent`. Ant `Parent` has only one properties. It's `name`.

```
Child child = new Child();
```

And in this case the type of the object is `Child`. Ant `Child` has two properties. They're `name` and  `salary`.

The fact is that there's no need to initialize non-final field immediately at the declaration. Usually this’s done at run-time because often you cannot know exactly what exactly implementation will you need. For example imagine that you have a class hierarchy with class `Transport` at the head. And three subclasses: `Car`, `Helicopter` and `Boat`. And there's another class `Tour` which has field `Transport`. That is:

```
class Tour {
   Transport transport;
}
```

As long as an user hasn't booked a trip and hasn't chosen a particular type of transport you can't initialize this field. It's first.

Second, assume that all of these classes must have a method `go()` but with a different implementation. You can define a basic implementation by default in the superclass `Transport` and own unique implementations in each subclass. With this initialization `Transport tran; tran = new Car();` you can call the method `tran.go()` and get result without worrying about specific implementation. It’ll call overrided method from particular subclass.

Moreover you can use instance of subclass everywhere where instance of superclass is used. For example you want provide opportunity to rent your transport. If you don't use polymorphism, you have to write a lot of methods for each case: `rentCar(Car car)`, `rentBoat(Boat boat)` and so forth. At the same time polymorphism allows you to create one universal method `rent(Transport transport)`. You can pass in it object of any subclass of `Transport`. In addition, if over time your logic will increase up and you'll need to create another class in the hierarchy? When using polymorphism you don't need to change anything. Just extend class `Transport` and pass your new class into the method:

```
public class Airplane extends Transport {
    //implementation
}
```

and `rent(new Airplane())`. And `new Airplane().go()` in second case.

Comment: that i know, but my question is why to do so? If we can do Parent p = new Parent() to get the parent reference.

Comment: This's [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). It's very useful. Polymorphism makes your program more flexible and extensible. How exactly can this be useful? See my examples in the [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12159881/944251).

Comment: Great example with transport... understood easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old thread but I came across the same doubt once.

So the concept of `Parent parent = new Child();` has something to do with early and late binding in java.

The binding of private, static and final methods happen at the compile as they cannot be overridden and the normal method calls and overloaded methods are example of early binding.

Consider the example:

```
class Vehicle
{
    int value = 100;
    void start() {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Started");
    }

    static void stop() {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Stopped");
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {

    int value = 1000;

    @Override
    void start() {
        System.out.println("Car Started");
    }

    static void stop() {
        System.out.println("Car Stopped");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Car extends Vehicle
        Vehicle vehicle = new Car();
        System.out.println(vehicle.value);
        vehicle.start();
        vehicle.stop();
    }
}
```

Output:
100

Car Started

Vehicle Stopped

This is happening because `stop()` is a static method and cannot be overridden. So binding of `stop()` happens at compile time and `start()` is non-static is being overridden in child class. So, the information about type of object is available at the run time only(late binding) and hence the `start()` method of Car class is called.

Also in this code the `vehicle.value` gives us `100` as the output because variable initialization doesn't come under late binding. ***Method overriding is one of the ways in which java supports run time polymorphism***.

- When an overridden method is called through a superclass reference, Java determines which version(superclass/subclasses) of that method is to be executed based upon the type of the object being referred to at the time the call occurs. Thus, this determination is made at run time.
- At run-time, it depends on the type of the object being referred to (not the type of the reference variable) that determines which version of an overridden method will be executed

I hope this answers where `Parent parent = new Child();` is important and also why you weren't able to access the child class variable using the above reference.

Answer (score 2):

This situation happens when you have several implementations.
Let me explain.
Supppose you have several sorting algorithm and you want to choose at runtime the one to implement, or you want to give to someone else the capability to add his implementation.
To solve this problem you usually create an abstract class (Parent) and have different implementation (Child).
If you write:

```
Child c = new Child();
```

you bind your implementation to Child class and you can't change it anymore. Otherwise if you use:

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

as long as Child extends Parent you can change it in the future without modifying the code.

The same thing can be done using interfaces: Parent isn't anymore a class but a java Interface.

In general you can use this approch in DAO pattern where you want to have several DB dependent implementations.
You can give a look at FactoryPatter or AbstractFactory Pattern.
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you'd like to have an array of instances of Parent class, and a set of child classes Child1, Child2, Child3 extending Parent. There're situations when you're only interested with the parent class implementation, which is more general, and do not care about *more specific stuff* introduced by child classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think all explanations above are a bit too technical for the people who are new to Object Oriented Programming (OOP). Years ago, it took me a while to wrap my head around this (as Jr Java Developer) and I really did no understand why we use a parent class or an interface to hide the actual class we are actually calling under the covers.

1. The immediate reason why is to hide complexity, so that the caller does not need to change often (be hacked and jacked in laymen's terms). This makes a lot of sense, especially if you goals is to avoid creating bugs. And the more you modify code, the more likely it is that you will have some of them creep up on you. On the other hand, if you just extend code, it is way less likely that you will have bugs because you concentrate on one thing at a time and your old code does not change or changes just a bit.
   Imagine that you have simple application that allows the employees in the medical profession to create profiles. For simplicity, let's assume that we have only GeneralPractitioners, Surgeons, and Nurses (in reality there are many more specific professions, of course). For each profession, you want to store some general information and some specific to that professional alone. For example, a Surgeon may have general fields like firstName, lastName, yearsOfExperience as general fields but also specific fields, e.g. specializations stored in an list instance variable, like List with contents simiar to "Bone Surgery", "Eye Surgery", etc. A Nurse would not have any of that but may have list procedures they are familiar with, GeneralPractioners would have their own specifics. As a result, how you save a profile of a specifics. However, you don't want your ProfileManager class to know about these differences, as they will inevitably change and increase over time as your application expands its functionality to cover more medical professions, e.g. Physio Therapist, Cardiologist, Oncologist, etc. All you want your ProfileManger to do is just say save(), no matter whose profile it is saving. Thus, it is common practice to hide this behind and Interface, and Abstract Class, or a Parent Class (if you plan to allow creating a general medical employee). In this case, let's choose a Parent class and call it MedicalEmployee. Under the covers, it can reference any of the above specific classes that extend it. When the ProfileManager calls myMedicalEmployee.save() the save() method will be polymorphically (many-structurally) be resolved to the correct class type that was used to create the profile originally, for example Nurse and call the save() method in that class.
2. In many cases, you don't really know what implementation you will need at runtime. From the example above, you have no idea if a GeneralPractitioner, a Surgeon, or a Nurse would create a profile. Yet, you know that you need to save that profile once completed, no matter what. MedicalEmployee.profile() does exactly that. It is replicated (overridden) by each specific type of MedicalEmployee - GeneralPractitioner, Surgeon, Nurse,
3. The result of (1) and (2) above is that you now can add new medical professions, implement save() in each new class, thereby overriding the save() method in MedicalEmployee, and you don't have to modify ProfileManager at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a simple example to answer to doubt.
The thing is, we use Parent Reference with Child Class Object
(Parent p = new Child()) To override Parent Method.

### Take this Example.

```
class Parent{
    public static void Method1(){
        System.out.println("Parent Static Method 1");
    }
    public void Method2(){
        System.out.println("Parent Non Static Method 2");
    }
    public static void ParentMethod3(){
        System.out.println("Parent Static Method 3");
    }
    public void ParentMethod4(){
        System.out.println("Parent Non Static Method 4");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    public static void Method1(){
        System.out.println("Child Static Method 1");
    }
    public void Method2(){
        System.out.println("Child Non Static Method 2");
    }
    public static void ChildMethod3(){
        System.out.println("Child Static Method 3");
    }
    public void ChildMethod4(){
        System.out.println("Child Non Static Method 4");
    }
}
```

Now Lets Execute:

```
class ParentChild {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //case1:Parent Reference with Parent Object
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.Method1();           //output: Parent Static Method 1
        parent.Method2();           //output: Parent Non Static Method 2
        parent.ParentMethod3();     //output: Parent Static Method 3
        parent.ParentMethod4();     //output: Parent Non Static Method 4

        //case2:Child Reference with Child Object
        Child child = new Child();
        child.Method1();           //output: Child Static Method 1
        child.Method2();           //output: Child Non Static Method 2
        child.ChildMethod3();     //output: Child Static Method 3
        child.ChildMethod4();     //output: Child Non Static Method 4

        //case3:Parent Reference with Child Object
        Parent pc = new Child();
        pc.Method1();           //output: Parent Static Method 1
        pc.Method2();           //output: Child Non Static Method 1
        pc.ParentMethod3();     //output: Parent Static Method 3
        pc.ParentMethod4();     //output: Parent Non Static Method 4
//        pc.ChildMethod3(); //Cannot call Child Methods from Parent Reference
//        pc.ChildMethod4(); //Cannot call Child Methods from Parent Reference`
 }
}`
```

As you can see, Parent Reference is calling Parent Methods
Child Reference is calling Child Methods

> Now, see Parent Reference with Child Class.   We are calling Method2
> from Parent Class. But, it is giving us Child Method.   So, we are
> doing Overriding here.
>
> Why Method1() didnt call Child Method? Bcoz it is a Static Method.
> Static means, it wont change. So, overriding wont work.   This concept
> is called Method Hiding.

.
The concept may be still blurry. First add this code to your IDE, run it and come back to this line.

> See, by using Parent Reference & Parent Object we can call Parent
> Methods as seen in Case1, by using Child Reference & Child Object we
> can call Child Methods as seen in Case2 But, in Case3, by using Parent
> Reference & Child Object we can call Both Parent Methods & Child
> Methods. We dont have to create 2 objects here, when the work can be
> done by creating only 1 object and saving memory.  So, it is mostly
> useful if you are using @Overriding concept.  Can be useful while
> extending abstract class & interface as well.

Answer (score -1):

for example we have a

```
class Employee

{

int getsalary()

{return 0;}

String getDesignation()

{

return “default”;

}

}

class Manager extends Employee

{

int getsalary()

{

return 20000;

}

String getDesignation()

{

return “Manager”

}

}

class SoftwareEngineer extends Employee

{

int getsalary()

{

return 20000;

}

String getDesignation()

{

return “Manager”

}

}
```

now if you want to set or get salary and designation of all employee (i.e software enginerr,manager etc )

we will take an array of Employee and call both method getsalary(),getDesignation

```
Employee arr[]=new Employee[10];

arr[1]=new SoftwareEngieneer();

arr[2]=new Manager();

arr[n]=…….

for(int i;i>arr.length;i++)

{

System.out.println(arr[i].getDesignation+””+arr[i].getSalary())

}
```

now its an kind of loose coupling because you can have different types of employees ex:softeware engineer,manager,hr,pantryEmployee etc

so you can give object to the parent reference irrespective of different employee object

Answer (score -3):

You declare parent as Parent, so java will provide only methods and attributes of the Parent class.

```
Child child = new Child();
```

should work. Or

```
Parent child = new Child();
((Child)child).salary = 1;
```

Comment: Of course this works. OP was asking for a context, where `Parent parent = new Child();` is useful / meaningful.

Comment: Its the same explanation as in the other answers, so why downvote this? I dont say i dont work, i say if you say Child c = new Parant() than you have an instance of Parent and not of Child, ando so you have no attribute salary. If you want the Attribute salary you need to create an instance of Child or cast Parent to Child....