# Java Instantiation Syntax

Tags: java, class, object, oop, instantiation

I am currently learning Java as a past time, and I am troubling in absorbing this instantiation syntax.
I know that if a `Main` class is created, I can create an object by using this

```
Main obj = new Main();
```

But in further lectures (specifically inheritance and polymorphism), they are creating objects as

```
Parentclass object = new Subclass();
```

I've tried using

```
Subclass object = new Subclass();
```

and have the same output.

Can you please tell me the difference about these two?

Comment: The difference is that if the variable `object` is defined as a `Parentclass` you can assign `Subclass` or `Parentclass` or `OtherSubclass` instances to it. It also means that you can only access the instance through the `Parentclass` interface, so if `Subclass` exposes additional methods they won't be callable.

Comment: Thank you very much @jonrsharpe. This is troubling me in the past lectures and I might miss something about this two syntaxes. thank you very much.

Comment: Also [Why do we assign a parent reference to the child object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159601/why-do-we-assign-a-parent-reference-to-the-child-object-in-java?rq=1)