# Calling child function using parent

Tags: php, architecture, structure

Hey guys got an architecture problem, I will explain the structure first

Service:

- TestService

Classes:

- InterfaceClass
- ParentClass
- FirstChildClass
- SecondChildClass
- ThirdChildClass

The Parent implements the interfaceClass and the childs extends the parentClass.

all childs have different functions, lets say firstfunction on FirstChildClass, secondfunction on SecondChildClass,

i want to call firstfunction on serice by calling only the parent, so for example ParentClass:init()->firstclass();

the language im gonna be using is PHP, anyone have any idea how can I implement such thing?

Comment: _I want to call firstfunction on service by calling only the parent, so for example ParentClass:init()->firstclass();_ In this case, your structure looks flawed. Can you share a small code snippet of what you wish to do?

Comment: @nice_dev hey! i don't have any snippets cause I didn't start writing anything yet, I'm trying to think about the best way to approach it.

I will explain what I'm trying to do, I got a BaseActivity class which has few child classes, MovieClass, WalkClass, GymClass, each one of them having different functions related to the specific activity, Im also having a service, what I'm trying to figure out is how I'm gonna be calling the child function, without making the function in the BaseActivity class.

Comment: Understood, you need generalized type. Is it ok if I share a small code snippet for demo purpose? I hope you can create object of child class in your Service class?

Comment: yeah ofc! @nice_dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a generalized reference variable(of the base superclass) in your `Service` class constructor to achieve this. It is called generalization and widening. In programming terms, we call it [`Upcasting`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159601/why-do-we-assign-a-parent-reference-to-the-child-object-in-java).

**BaseActivity class**

```
class BaseActivity{
    function base(){
        echo "from base", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**MovieClass class**

```
class MovieClass extends BaseActivity{
    function movie(){
        echo "from MovieClass", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**WalkClass class**

```
class WalkClass extends BaseActivity{
    function walk(){
        echo "from WalkClass", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Service class**

```
class Service{
    public $activity;
    function __construct(BaseActivity $b){ // here you have the base generalized reference of your hierarchy
        $this->activity = $b;
    }
}
```

**Driver Code:**

```
<?php

$service_A = new Service(new MovieClass());
$service_A->activity->movie();


$service_B = new Service(new WalkClass());
$service_B->activity->walk();
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/7e002)

**Note:** So whenever you pass the object to the `Service` class constructor, it has to be a type of `BaseActivity`.