# What is the difference between parent class data type vs child class data type?

Tags: parent-child

I'd like to ask for help with the next question. If I create 2 classes MyThing(parent) and MySubThing(extends parent). What's the difference if I create object like code below, each gives the same correct results. How does type of variable influences code later on?

```
MyThing myThing = new MySubThing();
//or
MySubThing myThing = new MySubThing();
```

I found first piece of code and tried to play with it, but looks like nothing unexpected happened.

This question came up when I studied Java for dummies 7th edition and code was there like this.

Comment: object is of the same type at runtime but statically speaking the variable is defined differently and it would behave differently at compile time in terms of dependencies. You should go in better details with polymorphism in OOP

Comment: Quite frankly, at very beginning when I went through the chapter 8 I didn't notice immediately that author creates object with parent class type. But than I said myself..."why he is doing that?"...so maybe he did it just for educational purposes not for how it should be correctly done.

Comment: since you can't still understand the why.. I would ask: did you read the text before and after the code. I mean what's the purpose of describing OOP inheritance in a book if you are not going to show what's the point of having a base class? there's nothing wrong at making an instance of a class that by pure chance is also a base class. The point is what are you going to do with that variable.. are you going to pass it as an argument of another method? which kind of dependency holds that method you are going to use.

Comment: OOP gives you the fundementals for Inheritance, Encapsulation and Polymorphism and those comes handy for design patterns. The question you are asking is just written in the book but you have to read it

Comment: anyway in short: even if the object is the same, the interface to communicate with the object in the first case is the MyThing class and in the second case is MySubThing class

Comment: I would say, I'm a little bit lost here pertaining to correlation between variable type and what can I assign into it, since when I create integer variable type I do int x = 6 and obviously its clear;...but here MyThing myThing = new MySubThing(); I thought only way to assign call to MySubThing constructor is MySubThing myThing = new MySubThing();....so with the same name(class name) of data type....I have to dive deeper into OOP, thx.

Comment: a class that inherits a base class means it shares the same interface plus something else (optionally). So such an object can be held inside a variable typed as the base class. The trick is that as that it will be compatible when passed to a function expecting a BaseClass type. So you can write a single method that will accept the BaseClass type as argument and yet obtain a different behaviour depending on which exact object there's behind. The closest idea to that was using Interfaces, this just goes a bit further

Comment: One last thing to better explode the concept: an object instance of ChildClass is expected to implement also the BaseClass interface when ChildClass ***extends BaseClass***.. and as that is valid if held in a variable typed as BaseClass

Comment: Just quick question related to this topic MyThing myThing = new MySubThing();. I found that if I add variable into parent class (let's say int x = 6;) and the same variable into child class(let's say int x=7;) with different value and I call this variable somewhere like myThing.x it returns always 6. Is only way to show right child value calling super() in child class constructor? Why child class simply doesn't overwrite it(the same variable/different values)?

Comment: I think you need to understand the basics.. you call it variable but it should be a member of the class (as a field, a property, a method or whatever the language of your choice decided to call it.). The point is that inheritance is about the class interface.

Comment: I found this article which is the closest to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159601/why-do-we-assign-a-parent-reference-to-the-child-object-in-java   Somewhere in the middle there is code where they call System.out.println(vehicle.value); output has 100, but expectation I assume 1000. Its  because variable initialization doesn't come under late binding. How to change code right way to get 1000 instead of 100. Thx.

Comment: you are narrowing down the talk on `fields` (that's how java calls what you called variable declared in the scope of a class). Those are something not strictly following the inheritance pattern because they don't strictly belongs to the interface of the class. So what's happening there is that the `Car` class inherits everything including `value` but it's later _shadowing_ the `value` field initializing it with a different literal. But the value returned by the field depends on which type you used to access it. In that case the variable is declared as the `Vehicle` type so `value` returns 100.

Comment: if instead of a field, it was a method like `getValue()` and it belonged to the `Vehicle` interface, you could override that method in your `Car` class and make it return `1000`... in that case also if the variable was declared as `Vehicle` since the object was `Car` it would return `1000`

Comment: Thanks for clue. I found link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C5RJMC2u90 where hiding/shadowing field is explained very well, so I share it here. The other way how to change field xy in child class is to call in child constructor field super.xy. Is there any advantage/benefit to change field within child class with override method instead of super or vice versa?