# How to check for type?

Tags: android, types, typechecking

In an Android app I've got a couple contacts from my contacts list. They can be either emails, phone numbers, or even other things. I now want to check which type it is and bind specific actions to them.

For example, if it is a type `vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2`, I want to send a POST message with just the email field, and if it is a type `vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2` I want to send a POST message with just the phone field.

Any ideas how I could check this?

Comment: Are you looking for `instance of` ? `email_v2`  is what ?

Comment: Those types are `String`s (or `Uri`s?) if I'm not mistaken and you can most likely simply [compare then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Please add a code snippet that shows how you get the type and what variable type it actually is / how you plan to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way to go would be using overloading:
You implement multiple methods with different input parameters but the same name, such as:

```
checkContact(email_v2 email){ do things with email }
checkContact(phone_v2 phone){ do things with phone }
checkContact(String s){do things with random string }
```

I think you get my point.
If you want a simple if-statement, though:

```
if (contact instanceof vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2){ do send }
```

Comment: That does not work in Java. The overloaded method is already selected at compiletime.

Comment: It works if you know the type at compile time but you can't use overloading to execute different methods based on the actual type at runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883414/is-there-any-reason-that-java-uses-late-static-binding-for-overloaded-methods-in (`catch` blocks do that though)

Comment: @zapl Alright, thanks, I see your point now :) -- I'm very new to Java myself (only worked with it less than a week)

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the class constant `CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` for your different types, something like:

```
contact.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.equals("vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2");
```