# Small misunderstanding of polymorphism in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

Hello I have an issue with polymorphism.

In general I think I have understood what it means.
I added a MWE below.

I expected that I get two times teh text `Using String` on the console. In fact I get both texts once. Why?

The reason is I want to create a pattern like the visitor pattern and I want to avoid chains of `if( ... instanceof ... )`. Therefore I thought I implement for each type a method (here `String` and `Object`) that are overloaded.

The question is now how to make java select the correct method.

PS: The reason I have this problem is that I have to 'box' the elementary types into classes for furthe use. Therefore I have to test for `Integer`, `Boolean`, ... This is also the reason why I cannot simple extend the class and use a common method.

```
public class TestOverload
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "abc";
        Object o = s;

        TestOverload test = new TestOverload();
        test.doSomething(s);
        test.doSomething(o);
    }

    public void doSomething(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("Using Object");
    }

    public void doSomething(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("Using String");
    }
}
```

Comment: Java uses late/static binding for method arguments (Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883414/is-there-any-reason-that-java-uses-late-static-binding-for-overloaded-methods-in?rq=1) question is useful). I think I'm afraid you'll have to chain `instanceof` to select the appropriate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java virtual machine, methods are determined with their names, argument types, and and return type. This is why two or more methods with the same name can coexist - because their "full names" are different.
Java compiler selects most appropriate method to call so that minimal argument type conversion required (and disregards the return type). So it selects `doSomething(String s)` for the first case and`doSomething(Object o)` for the second. At run time, methods selected at compile time are invoked, so the actual type of `Object o` does not matter.

If you box simple types into Integer and Boolean, there is no other way to determine the actual type except for `instanceof`. Consider boxing into your own types which can be extended.