# How does Java decide between methods with the same name with different parameter types?

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class Main {
    public void testMethod(Object o){
        System.out.println("Object Method called");
    }
    public void testMethod(String s){
        System.out.println("String Method called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().testMethod(null);
    }
}
```

This program magically calls String method? On what criteria Java compiler decided to go with String method?  Can somebody please point me the reason for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule is that the compiler chooses the "most specific" overload out of all matches. Since String is a subclass of Object, that makes the String version "more specific", and hence it is chosen

Comment: And, if you want to use the Object method, you can cast the parameter to an Object -- `new Main().testMethod((Object)null);`

Answer (score 2):

The operative part of the Java Language Specification is [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5):

> *"If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.*
>
> *The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error."*

The JLS then proceeds to give a detailed technical specification of how to determine the most specific method.

Answer (score 0):

Addressed here:

[Overloaded method selection based on the parameter's real type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type)