# What is the type on null as a method argument?

Tags: java

So here it is this example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    new Stuff(null);
    new Stuff("a");
    new Stuff(1);           
}
```

and class Stuff is defined as follow

```
public class Stuff {    
       Stuff(Object o){
           System.out.println("object");        
       }

       Stuff(String s){
           System.out.println("string");        
       }

}
```

The output is

```
string
string
object
```

How does Java tell the `null` is a `String`? If I change `Stuff` to

```
public class Stuff {    

       Stuff(String s){
           System.out.println("string");        
       }

       Stuff(Integer o){
           System.out.println("Integer");           
       }

}
```

I get compilation error for `Stuff(null)`:

```
The constructore Stuff(String) is ambigous.
```

Again, why does Java "decide" `null` is a `String`?

Comment: Because String is the closest thing to `null` among all others: "*The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen*".

Comment: Worth mentioning that `null` is not a string, or an object, or an integer. (It's just the explicit lack of them).

Comment: Since the comment isn't generated: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13033037/1864167

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- The compiler first lists all applicable methods. In your case, both are applicable.
- It then tries to find a method which is more specific than the other(s).
- In your first example, `String` is a subclass of `Object` and is therefore more specific.
- In your second example, both methods are applicable (String and Integer) but neither is more specific than the other (String is not a subclass of Integer which is not a subclass of String). So there is an ambiguity, hence the compiler error.

The full algorithm to determine which method should be chosen is defined in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).

Answer (score 6):

Because String is more specific then Object. Java always tries to use more specific match when figuring out which constructor or method to use.

Comment: +1 and neither Integer or String is more specific than the other.