# why this code does not give compilation error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Java uses early binding to determine which method to call, but here my question is how is it determining that it should call

> private static void confuse(RuntimeException object)

not the other two methods ?

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    confuse(null);
}

private static void confuse(Object object) {
    System.out.println("object");

}

private static void confuse(RuntimeException object) {
    System.out.println("RuntimeException ");

}
private static void confuse(Exception object) {
    System.out.println("Exception ");

}
```

if I am calling confuse using null it should give compilation error, as null can be the value for all three classes. Please explain the output.

Comment: I have read the answers on that question and still that does not answer how is it calling private static void confuse(RuntimeException object) not the other two

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13033089/116249

Comment: I was a little eager on that close. Basically, `RuntimeException` is a more specific type than the others, so it is chosen. There are other duplicates around.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Now I got my answer so we can close this :)

Comment: @Patrick thanks for the link this answers my question

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis it has an exact duplicate see above this comment. It explains why RuntimeException will be called this time.