# Java overloading method selection

Tags: java, overloading

I'm trying to get my head round how Java selects which method is executed:

```
//Example 1 prints Square:add(Figure)
Figure fs = new Square();
fs.add(fs);

//Example 2 prints Square:add(Figure)
Rectangle rs = new Square();
rs.add(fs);

//Example 3 prints Rectangle:add(Rectangle). Expected Square:add(Square)
rs.add(new Square());

//Example 4 prints Rectangle:add(Rectangle). Expected Square:add(Figure)
Square ss = new Square();
ss.add(rs);

class Figure
{
    public void add(Figure f){ System.out.println("Figure:add(Figure)"); }
}

class Rectangle extends Figure
{
    @Override
    public void add(Figure f){ System.out.println("Rectangle:add(Figure)"); }
    public void add(Rectangle r){ System.out.println("Rectangle:add(Rectangle)"); }
}

class Square extends Rectangle
{
    @Override
    public void add(Figure f){ System.out.println("Square:add(Figure)"); }
    public void add(Square s){ System.out.println("Square:add(Square)"); }
}
```

What I've learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type) is

- Method signature gets determined based on compile time data types
- Actual method invoked depends on the dynamic type of the object the method is called on.

Based on that, the result of the first two calls is as expected. However, I don't understand the result of example 3 and 4.

It seems to be specified in the [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), but I don't understand it.

Comment: As an author of this assignment question I can confirm that the provided answers are correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> However, I don't understand the result of example 3 and 4.

Okay, let's look at them individually.

**Example 3**

```
//Example 3 prints Rectangle:add(Rectangle). Expected Square:add(Square)
rs.add(new Square());
```

The important parts are the *compile-time* types of the expressions `rs` and `new Square()`.

`rs` is only declared as `Rectangle`, so the compiler will look at the methods declared by `Rectangle` and its superclasses:

```
public void add(Figure f)
public void add(Rectangle r)
```

The type of the expression `new Square()` is `Square`, so both methods are *applicable* - but the second one is more *specific*.

So the compiler will call `add(Rectangle)` on the object that `rs` refers to. That's it for the compile-time side.

At execution time, the value of `rs` refers to an instance of `Square` - but `Square` doesn't override `add(Rectangle)` so the method picked is the implementation in `Rectangle`:

```
public void add(Rectangle r){ System.out.println("Rectangle:add(Rectangle)"); }
```

**Example 4**

```
//Example 4 prints Rectangle:add(Rectangle). Expected Square:add(Figure)
Square ss = new Square();
ss.add(rs);
```

Again, let's consider the compile-time types involved... `ss` is of type `Square`, and `rs` is of type `Rectangle` (compile-time types, remember).

The methods declared by `Square` and its superclasses are:

```
public void add(Figure f)
public void add(Rectangle r)
public void add(Square s)
```

As the compile-time type of `rs` is only `Rectangle` (not `Square`), the first two methods are applicable, but the third isn't. Therefore, again, `add(Rectangle)` is picked at compile time (as it's more specific than `add(Figure)`).

Again, the execution time type of `ss` is `Square`, which doesn't override `add(Rectangle)`, so the implementation in `Rectangle` is used.

Let me know if anything in here is confusing - if you can be specific about which part, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

```
rs.add(new Square());
```

The declared type of rs is Rectangle. So it looks at a method in Rectangle and all superclasses taking a Square or a type compatible with Square as argument. The most specific one is `add(Rectangle)` since  Square is a Rectangle, and since Rectangle is more specific than Figure.

```
Square ss = new Square();
ss.add(rs);
```

Looks for a method `add(Rectangle)` in Square and all super-classes. `Rectangle.add(Rectangle)` is chosen, since `Square.add(Square)` doesn't apply (a Rectangle is not a Square), and `Square.add(Figure)` is less specific.