# java polymorphism late binding rules

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I am trying to do some polymorphism exercises and I cannot figure out how this kind of polymorphism works. I did not find any deep information about this kind of exercised. I hope you guys could give me some explanation.

exercise 1:

```
class Top {
    public void m( Middle p ) System.out.print("A ");
}

class Middle extends Top {
    public void m( Object p ) System.out.print("M ");
    public void m( Middle p ) System.out.print("L ");
}

class Bottom extends Middle {
    public void m( Object p ) System.out.print("V ");
    public void m( Middle p ) System.out.print("X ");
}

class Test {
    public static void run() {
        Top tm = new Middle();
        Middle mb = new Bottom();

        tm.m (mb);            -> L
        tm.m(new Bottom());   -> L   why?
        mb.m(mb);             -> X
        mb.m(tm);             -> V   why?
        mb.m(new Middle());   -> X
        new Bottom().m(tm);   -> V
    }
}
```

exercise 2:

```
class Top {
    public void gg( Top o ) System.out.print("A ");
    public void gg( Middle m ) System.out.print("B ");
}

class Middle extends Top {
    public void gg( Top o ) System.out.print("L ");
    public void gg( Bottom b ) System.out.print("M ");
}

class Bottom extends Middle {
    public void gg( Top o ) System.out.print("X ");
    public void gg( Middle m) System.out.print("Z ");
}

class Test {
    public static void run() {
        Top oo = new Top();
        Top ff = new Middle();
        Bottom uu = new Bottom();

        oo.gg(ff);      -> A
        oo.gg(uu);      -> A   why?
        ff.gg(ff);      -> L
        ff.gg(uu);      -> B   why?
        uu.gg(ff);      -> X
        uu.gg(uu);      -> X   why?
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Greets

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676395/java-overloading-method-selection

Comment: Some of the answers for exercise 2 are wrong, if you actually run the code, which probably explains your difficulty. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In all of these cases, the methods that *can be considered* depend on the compile-time type of the variable, but the method that is *actually called* depends on the runtime type of the object. So for

```
Top ff = new Middle();
```

the methods of `Middle` are the ones that will be called - but these may be inherited from Top, and we can only call methods that are available in `Top` at compile time, because `ff` is declared as a `Top`.

To determine which of the overloaded methods is called, we look at the parameter type, and choose the most specific method. So if we have to choose between:

```
public void m( Object p ) System.out.print("M ");
public void m( Middle p ) System.out.print("L ");
```

and we are passing a `Bottom`, then the second method will be chosen. You can think of `Bottom` as being closer to `Middle` than `Object` in the class hierarchy:

```
Bottom -> Middle -> Top -> Object
```

Finally, some of your answers are just wrong (exercise 2) - I suggest you try running the code, which may need a bit of tweaking so it actually compiles.

```
oo.gg(uu); // -> A why?  -- actually produces B
uu.gg(uu); // -> X why?  -- actually produces M
```