# Java Polymorphism Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class B{
  void print(String s){
            System.out.println('B');
     }
}

class D extends B{
  public void print(Object o){
           System.out.println('D');
     }
}

public class TestB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D();
        d.print("Test");

    }

}
```

Hi all may i know how does one determine which print method does this d.print uses and any reason for it?
I understand that there is no upcasting nor method overriding here. So would the print method be used in class D since Object is a superclass of String?

Comment: Your above code wouldn't compile in first place.

Comment: have you tried writing this code (without the error(s)), compiling and running it?

Comment: may i ask why??

Comment: hi yes i did if u meant the issue with the main function not typed out entirely then that is not the issue i am just referring to the main function that i create a D object and call the print

Comment: so, run it and see what result it gives

Comment: the result is B but i have no idea why is it B

Comment: You declare your object as `D d`, that determines what method calls are available during compile time. Your class `D` has 2 overloaded methods `print`, one that accepts any Object and one that accepts a String. You call the print method and pass a String as an argument, so the compiler decides that `print(String s)` fits better than  `print(Object o)`

Comment: Note that if you change your call to `d.print((Object)"Test");` it will call the `print(Object o)` method. And any good IDE should show you what overloaded method will be called even before compiling.

Comment: How about if now class B and D is in a package p1 and the class TestB is now in a subpackage eg(p1.s1). Why would the result change to D?

Comment: can it be explained due to the visibility of class B fun function is default and hence is not visible from the subpackage p1.s1 and Java sees subpackages as a seperate package.

Comment: There's no such thing as a subpackage. TestB cannot access either B or D because they are in another package and they're not public.

Comment: i understand sorry if my scenario was not clear enough. It is assuming that the class B and D are now public class in package p1 but the main point is that because p1.s1 is seen as a seperate package and hence is unable to access the default void fun method in class B and hence it uses the class D method

Comment: Then it would choose D.print because that's public, while B.print is inaccessible because it's package-private.

Comment: Okay understood thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java overloading method selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676395/java-overloading-method-selection)

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is called `Method Overloading`.

The code inside the main method you tell the program to create an instance of class `D` and calling method `print` with a `String` parameter.

Because this is `Method Overloading` and not `Method Overriding` also the data type inside the parameter is Strint, Java runtime chooses the original method to run.

To make this code Method overriding both method in both classes need to have same type of parameter like this:

```
class B{
  public void print(String s){
            System.out.println('B');
     }
}

class D extends B{
  public void print(String o){
           System.out.println('D');
     }
}

public class TestB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D();
        d.print("Test");

    }

}
```

Output:

```
D
```

Or if you want the program to be method overloading and still show output `D`, you need to declare **"Test"** as an Object variable or cast it to Object:

```
class B{
  public void print(String s){
            System.out.println('B');
     }
}

class D extends B{
  public void print(Object o){
           System.out.println('D');
     }
}

public class TestB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D();
        // casting
        d.print((Object)"Test");
        
        // variable
        Object t = "Test";
        
        d.print(t);

    }

}
```