# Java method overload choice

Tags: java

I have two methods in a class...

```
public void method(String var1, String var2, Object var3) {
    //do stuff
}

public void method(String var1, String var2, Object[] var3) {
    //do stuff
}
```

When I make the following call... `obj.method("string", "string", obj)` the correct method is called, however, when I try to call `obj.method("string", "string", obj[])` the first incarnation of that method is called.

Is there any annotation or "hint" I can give to make sure the method I anticipate being called will be called? I know an `Object[]` is an`Object`, but I would hope that at runtime the method with `Object[]` would be called before `Object`.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Passing an `Object[]` will call the second method.

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. If I use reference of type `Object` I will invoke first version of method. If I would use `Object[]` reference second method will be invoked.

Comment: Remove the first method and pass an array of one element in the situation where you would have used the first method.

Comment: You can always cast the third argument to `Object[]`.

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: Yeah... it looks like I used my SO lifeline too quickly... it IS working properly... the method call that was failing was actually trying to send in String[], not Object[], however, I still wonder why it was calling the method with Object and not Object[] (it seems to me that Object[] is more of a match than Object

Comment: @ElGuapo Again, I get the expected behaviour which is that the method with `Object[]` is called when passing in a String array... works for me.

Comment: hmmm... who knows... what I do know is I've coded-around it for now... thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, for me this calls the second method as expected!

In the case where you want one to be called over the other, then the hint you'd give is usually a cast to the exact parameter type expected by the method (this cast will work even on `null`.) So using `(Object)arr` would force the first method to be called, but by default it will definitely call the second method (on all correct versions of the JVM anyway - contrary to popular belief, this scenario is covered explicitly in the JLS and thus is not ambiguous.)

Comment: Indeed, it must call the second method by the language specification.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1572499/877472) also provides a pretty good explanation of method selection.

Comment: It also doesn't happen to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the method overload happens during compile time. That means which method is called was decided during program compilation. Note this is different from method overriding.