# how does the groovyc work?

Tags: groovy, compilation

It seems the groovy also support the compiling mode, using `groovyc` , If  I  run the following code with dynamic script calling way, I will get "String" method called.

Why I still got "String" even if I compiled the code using `groovyc`? The type of variable a is "Object", so I expected after compiling the code, I will get the "Object" function called.

```
Object a = "123"

def foo(Object a) {
    println "Object"
}

def foo(String a) {
    println "String"
}

foo(a)
```

Comment: Object a = "123" is like Object a=(GString) "123"... it  will get dispatched to most matching method call..

Comment: related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type  (foo is a method on a Class that represents your script )

Comment: Why would you expect the semantics to change after compilation?

Comment: @jayan: that link is about the *opposite* behaviour to what the OP is observing...

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth : I posted the link hastily. Groovy has section about the diff with Java. This is one, and exact opposite behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is relevant section from [groovy-docs](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html)

> In Groovy, the methods which will be invoked are chosen at runtime.
>   This is called runtime dispatch or multi-methods. It means that the
>   method will be chosen based on the types of the arguments at runtime.
>   **In Java, this is the [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type)**: methods are chosen at compile time,
>   based on the declared types.

There is a sample code in '2. Multi-methods' [section](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_multi_methods), not copying here.

Finally mandatory link to MrHaki's [groovy goodness page on this topic](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/09/groovy-goodness-multimethods-or.html)