# Can you access subclass variables with object of superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

In the following code, I pass to the method "testmethod() an instantiation of a subclass of A, named B

Unfortunately, the signature for the method accepts the superclass A not the subclass B 
and I can't change that signature since it's referred by many classes.

Is there a way (without changing the signature of testmethod()) that I can access the var2 variable from within testmethod() that is part of the object that was passed to testmethod?

```
    public class test5  {

        public static void main(String args[]){
            B b = new B();
            testmethod(b);
        }

        public static void testmethod(A a2 ) {
            System.out.println("in testmeth->" + a2.getVar1() );   // WORKS
            System.out.println("in testmeth->" + a2.getVar2() );   // DOESNT WORK
        }
    }

    class A  {
        int var1 = 2;

        public int getVar1() {
            return var1;
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        int var2 = 8;

        public int getVar2() {
            return var2;
        }
```

Comment: You really shouldn't *need* to do this.  If `testmethod()` requests an instance of `A` then it should use the operations on `A`.  If it needs a `B`, then the method signature should require a `B`.

Comment: Or you could overload the method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast like this:

```
if(a2 instanceof B)
  System.out.println("in testmeth->" + ((B) a2).getVar2() );
else
  System.out.println("in testmeth->" + a2.getVar1() );
```

Comment: In the code sample in question, the instance of adds no value as its explicitly a B type already.

Comment: That's true, but the OP mentioned that it's used by many classes, therefore it might have been used while passing an instance of A instead. @tgkprog

Comment: Worked perfectly, requiring no method signature change!

Comment: @user3302169 Glad that was helpful. And for the -1 ... haters gonna hate :)

Answer (score 3):

You can **downcast** but this is generally not a good practice.

So it would be

```
System.out.println("in testmeth->" + ((B) a2).getVar2() );
```

Note: if `a2` is not an `instanceof` the class `B` then this line would result in a `ClassCastException`

Comment: Worth mentioning `ClassCastException`, `instanceof` any _why_ this, which it might seem amazing at first, always ends in tears...

Comment: Worked perfectly for me...in conjunction to using the instanceof conditional to avoid the exception

Comment: @user3302169 generally speaking, usage of `instanceof` signifies bad code. Avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 2):

You could *overload* the method, and then the most specific one will be chosen when called. ie:

```
public class test5  {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        testmethod(a);
        testmethod(b);
    }

    public static void testmethod(A a2 ) {
        System.out.println("in testmeth_a->" + a2.getVar1() );
    }

    public static void testmethod(B b2 ) {
        System.out.println("in testmeth_b->" + b2.getVar2() );
    }
}
```

NB. The method called depends on the *declared* type and not the type of the object passed in. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the minimal example, but it looks like you might want to make `A` an abstract class, which requires `B` (and any other subclasses) to implement `getVar2()`. When you do this, `getVar2` is accessible through any instance of `A`:

```
abstract class A {
   int var1 = 2;

    public int getVar1() {
        return var1;
    }
    public abstract int getVar2();
}
```