# Unexpected overloaded method compiler selection with null parameter

Tags: java, overloading, scjp

I am very surprised why output is very much different from what I am expecting , I have two overloaded methods, one having one String and the other an Object as parameter, while calling this method with null parameter, output is just printing
`"String"` 
and not calling method having object as parameter.

Why does Java selects the method having String as parameter, how java determines which overloaded method to call ?

```
class TestingClass {
    public void test(String s) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public void test(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestingClass q = new TestingClass();
        q.test(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Repeat it after me. Overriding happens only in derived classes and that too only if the method parameters are the same. The return type is allowed to be covariant.

Comment: A more detailed text explaining what Eran has said. [Look for Denis answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type)

Answer (score 2):

There is no overriding in this code, only method overloading. When the compiler has to choose which of the two `test` methods to execute (since `null` can be passed to both), it chooses the one with the more specific argument type - `test(String s)` - `String` is more specific than `Object` since it is a sub-class of `Object`.

The other method can be called using :

```
q.test((Object) null);
```

Comment: how string is more specific than Object ?

Comment: @jk2praj A sub-class is more specific than its super-class. That's how the term "more specific" is defined in the JLS.

Comment: Because String is a sub class of Object. If however the classes are not related by inheritance hierarchy then you will get a compile time error

Answer (score 0):

Without adding a possible new answer, let me suggest you to extend your code like following,

```
public class Overload {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Overload().test(null);
    }

    public void test(String s) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public void test(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public void test(Integer s) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

}
```

Comment out any one of Object or Integer version any see it for yourself. The answer being already provided by others.