# Double Dispatch when having a method that accepts Object class

Tags: java, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

I have an Implementation of a Mapper class which accepts Object as parameter in one of the `map(Object object)` functions. The rest `map(T t)` functions accept Integer or Class etc.

When I try to pass an int it gets Autoboxed into Integer and invokes the `map(Object object)` instead of the `map(Integer integer)`.

I have done some research for Double Dispatch and saw that I could use the Visitor Pattern. But this does not apply in my case because I do not pass custom Objects that I could have them implement an interface with `accept()`.

The aforementioned method accepts every object.

Is there any kind of solution for Double Dispatching with Java objects when you have a method that accepts Object as well?

```
public BaseMatcher map(Object object) {
        return something();
    }

    public BaseMatcher map(Integer integer) {
        return somethingOther();
    }

    public BaseMatcher map(Class<? extends Exception> klass) {
        return somethingOtherOther();
    }
```

The call on these map() functions, would be as follows: `foo(Object object) { mapper.map(object); }` which leads to `map(Object object)` being invoked.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type. For determine the signature of the method being invoked, it's using the compile time type (`Object`), not the run time type.

Comment: @JMSilla I have already searched for every possible case. That's why I asked, because I am trying to see if there is a possible solution to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the compiler knows about your objects is that they're objects, i.e. instance of Object. So `map(Object)` is being called.

If your map method needs to do something different based on the type of the object being passed, then it should get the concrete type of the object, and act accordingly (using `instanceof`, `getClass()`, or whataver).

The alternative is indeed to use polymorphism. But to do that, the caller will have to provide a collection of Mappable, instead of just a collection of objects:

```
private interface Mappable {
    BaseMatcher mapMe(Mapper mapper);
}

public class IntegerMappable {
    private final Integer value;

    public IntegerMappable(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseMatcher mapMe(Mapper mapper) {
        return mapper.map(this.value);
    }
}
```

And when you want to map objects, you wrap them into the appropriate Mappable (or use a lambda):

```
List<Mappable> mappables = new ArrayList<>();
mappables.add(new IntegerMappable(2));
mappables.add(new StringMappable("hello");
mappables.add(mapper -> mapper.map(42));
```

Comment: Yes, the thing is that I was trying to avoid having 20-30 lines with checks for instanceOf. Is there an example with the Mappable collection you mentioned last?