# Dynamically call overloaded method reference based on List Object's type?

Tags: java, reflection, collections, java-8, java-stream

Say I have a Java controller class, which I want to have a method that applies a transform to each object in a List/Collection depending on the type of that object. The transforms are of the same name, and are overloaded [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) that convert to a common type based on the parameter type. See the example below.

```
public static List<String> convertList(List<? extends Object> list) {
    return list.stream().map(POJO::convert).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static String convert(POJO p) {
    return p.toString();
}

public static String convert(POJO2 p) {
    return p.toString();
}
```

The above gives an error Incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R

It works, of course, if I set the method signature to `convertList(List<POJO> list)`, but then it only works for one of the object types. How can I use something like reflection or lazy casting to get one method to work for both convert functions? I cannot edit the class definitions of either POJO or POJO2.

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis I am not sure the solution should be added as one of the answer to the question you have linked. The accepted answer states that you can't do that, because it's a different question. If you believe it is answer there can you add a link to it?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sorry, say that again. I'm not sure what you're asking of me.

Comment: Some people get very annoyed when I reopen questions to give an answer, and I have no interest in putting code in a comment. I will wait for it to be reopened, or not. ;)

Comment: It's not clear how marking this question as a duplicate of a different question, with different answers is helpful in this case. None of the answers given answers this question, nor should one be added IMHO.

Comment: @PeterLawrey My understanding of this question is that they have a `List` of `Object` values for which they want to invoke a `convert` method corresponding to each value's  runtime type. That's what the other question is also asking and what the answer explain cannot be done directly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "How can I use something like reflection" which I would have assumed even if the OP hadn't mentioned it. The other question doesn't involve reflection at all.

Comment: @PeterLawrey An answer does, though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so could you add a link to it because the accepted answer states it can't be done which is not the right answer here.

Comment: @PeterLawrey [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10439746/438154)? Don't rely on comments. The duplicate post is already linked. All answers there are valid. Java does not resolve overloads "dynamically". Other solutions exist and are described.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Obviously you couldn't use Alex's answer. Though it could bring you to ask how reflection might help as the OP has done.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis which is what is what the OP is specially asking about and is not covered by that answer. The OP clearly knows what you have linked to already as he/she has mentioned int he question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've lost you again. What do you mean _couldn't use Alex's answer_? Duplicates link to questions, not answers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What have they linked to already? The method reference tutorial?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if two questions have different and incompatible answers  why would it be a good idea to link them?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no link, I read the the contents of the question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey _How can I use something like reflection or lazy casting to get one method to work for both convert functions_ Accepted answer: _In Java, dynamic method dispatch happens only for the object the method is called on, not for the parameter types of overloaded methods._. Another: _Ability to dispatch a call to a method based on types of arguments is called multiple dispatch. In Java this is done with Visitor pattern._ Another: _The typical pattern for working around this is to check the object type in the method with the Object signature and delegate to the method with a cast._ And on

Comment: @PeterLawrey All of those are valid and answer this question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't see how these answer "How can I use something like reflection or lazy casting to get one method to work for both convert functions?" However since the OP is silent, I guess you might be right.