# How is multimethod selection being used in this java example?

Tags: java, multimethod

```
class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        A j = new B();
        B k = new B();

        System.out.println(j.foo(k));
    }
}

class A {
public int foo(A p) { return 1; }
}
class B extends A {
public int foo(A p) { return 2; }
public int foo(B p) { return 3; }
}
```

So the output printed would be 2. I don't understand how this is so. Would the `j` object not be seen as its compiled form: `A` ? Yet it executes the class `B` version of `foo` using an `A` type parameter even though `k` is of class `B` at both compile and run time. Why is this so?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] - with focus on **minimal**? Class C and local variable i, l and m are irrelevant to your question. (And confusing to people)

Comment: I apologize for that. I created C and the other variables for testing purposes but weren't currently using them. I've since made an edit with only useful information.

Comment: Since you overwrote `foo(A p)` wihtin `B`, you cannot call `foo(A p)` from `A` on an object, that has the runtime- (or dynamic-)type ( `B` (variable `j` has static type `A` and runtime-type `B`). But since you access `j` through static type `A`, you can only call methods defined within `A`, thus `foo(B p)` is not accessible. This is why `foo(A p)` of class `B` is called.

Comment: The key to understanding this case is to appreciate that Java resolves method signatures at compile time and method implementation at runtime.   j is declared as type A, and A does not have a method on it of type 'foo(B)'.  However B is assignment compatible with A, thus at compile time it is selecting foo(A).   At runtime it is thus scanning an object of type B for a method with signature foo(A).  Even though B does have a method called foo(B), it will never look at that because of the decisions made at compile time.

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate with another question that is broader than this question and it is difficult to pull out a clear answer for this question from the referenced question.

Comment: Ah okay thanks to the both of you! I don't think I completely understood how compile time selection works! If `A` theoretically had `foo(B)` method, I'm guessing it would be able to choose `B`s version `foo(B)`?

Comment: @Taylor that is right.   Give it a go, I predict that it will change from printing 2 to 3.

Comment: @ChrisK Perfectly clear. Broader questions are better duplicate target, because they are broader and explain the problem better. This is the concept of canonical question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The following SO question provides a description of compile time vs runtime resolution.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type