# Prints null but doesn't throw exception

Tags: java

In Java, I understand that whenever we print object reference, internally toString() will be called. By default, toString() will print in this format "classname@hashcode". If this is true, then the following snippet should raise Null Pointer exception. Why does it not happen?

```
int[][] a = new int[3][];
System.out.println(a);  --> Prints [a@xxxxx
System.out.println(a[0]); --> Prints null (It should have thrown Null pointer Exception?)
```

Could some one help me understand this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The OP's not trying to fix a NPE, but rather trying to figure out why there isn't one being thrown.

Comment: The first println is printing an object reference which uses the default formatter, while the second is printing a pointer. Outputting a pointer does not dereference the pointer, just prints it. And Java has the formatter overloaded to check for null and print "null". Kinda nice really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `println()` doesn't invoke `toString()`. Instead, it invokes `String.valueOf(x)`, which checks if `x` is `null` to prevent `NullPointerException`.

Check these documentation pages (or just look into the source code of `PrintStream`):

[PrintStream.println(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-)

[String.valueOf(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I've checked the source code.                                        public static String More ...valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}

Comment: BTW this : `System.out.println(String.valueOf(null));` invokes an NPE.

Comment: @Abhijith that's because `String.valueOf(null)` goes to the `static String valueOf(char data[])` method. It's because compiler chooses to invoke *the most specific* method that fits. And the method that takes `Object` is, obviously, less specific than method that takes `char[]`. You can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1572499/1553934

Answer (score 1):

It because in a 2D Array defined as [x][y] the x index holds the reference of the y which is a array of y elements.

So when you printed `System.out.println(a);`it gave its toString representtion.
And when you inquired as System.out.println(a[0]); it was having a null reference hence it printed null

Answer (score 0):

println checks for null and instead print null, without calling toString. It is something like: println(Object x){  out.append( (x!=null)?x.toString():"null" ); out.append("\n"); }

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not null, you declare what a is in the first line `int[][] a = new int[3][];` you never declare or set `a[0]` however so it is null. You can print this value and pass this value around without causing a null pointer exception.  You get a null pointer exception when you try and call a method on a null value. So you would get a null pointer exception if you called `a[0].toString()` or any other method on that null value.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html