# Java method overloading parameter management

Tags: java

suppose I have a two methods defined in on class as following

```
public void m(final Serializable s){
    System.out.println("method 1");
}

public void m(final String s){
    System.out.println("method 2");
}
```

if I have a variable defined as

```
final Serializable s = "hello world";
```

How can I use this variable to invoke m so that "method 2" will be printed on the console? I have tried

```
m(s.getClass().cast(s));
```

but still method 1 is invoked, but the above code does cast s to String type from my observation.

Comment: `m((String)s); ` or `m(s.toString())` if you want this to work for all reference types.

Comment: instead of final Serializable s = "hello world"; use final String s = "hello  world"; ot cast the param

Comment: @Eran I can't do explicit casting since there are other variables like Integer.. etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloaded method selection based on the parameter's real type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `s` is of type `Serializable`, but in fact it points to a `String` object (since the literal `"hello world"` gives you an object of that type), so it can be cast to `(String)`.

Overloaded method calls are resolved at compile time using the most specific type available (known at compile time); what you are doing here, is trying to resolve using the most specific type known at run-time.

In Java you could do that using the Visitor pattern, (but unfortunately you can't extend `String`; you can if you declare your own types).

Comment: A nice and clean answer, clarifying the problem. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (s instanceof String)
  m((String)s);
else
  m(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to a String in several ways like:

```
m((String) s);
```

or:

```
m(s.toString());
```

Or you can initialize a String variable with s and invoke the method with it like:

```
String invoker = "" + s;
m(invoker);
```