# Forcing most specific method

Tags: java

I have interface `A` and, extending from it classes `AB`, `AC` and `AD`. I call a method giving me `A` (actually an instance of `AB`, `AC`, or `AD`). I have created following code:

```
private parse(A arg){
    throw new NotSupportedException("We don't support:" + arg.getClass());
}

private parse(AB arg){
    //do something
}
private parse(AC arg){
    //do something
}

private void doStuff(){
    parse(somethingThatReturnsSomeInstanceOfA());
}
```

The idea is, that I need to do different things based on the actual type I have. I have no control over these interfaces, so I can't move my parse methods there. I wanted to leverage Java behaviour of choosing the most specific overloaded method. You'll note that I don't have a method for `AD` - I don't want to implement specific behaviour for all extending interfaces, hence the method accepting A throwing exception.

That however doesn't work. Even when `getClass()` returns `AB` when calling `parse()` I always end up in `parse(A)`. Why? And is there a way to fix it? I don't want to do a lot of `ifs` and `instanceofs`...

Comment: How are those instances declared?

Comment: I suspect that `somethingThatReturnsSomeInstanceOfA()` has a return type `A` and thus all the JVM knows is that `parse(A)` needs to get called.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too @Thomas but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type

Comment: You need double dispatch aka Visitor pattern: https://www.google.com/search?q=double+dispatch+java&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS790US790&oq=double+dispatch+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4438j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8