# what is the runtime type object in this

Tags: java, polymorphism

1. I am overriding 2 methods of parent in child class and I'm not getting 
   how `Object ooj = new String("abc");` is working
2. as per I'm considered runtime object is of string type but when I pass `obj` to function it invokes the method with `Object` type

---

```
PARENT CLASS
public class Parent {
    public void function(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("I'm  parent Object Type");
    }

    public void function(String str) {
        System.out.println("I'm parent String");
    }
}

CHILD CLASS

public class Chile extends Parent{
    public void function(Object oob) {
        System.out.println("I'm child object");
    }
    public void function(String str) {
        System.out.println("I'm child string");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Chile();
        Object obj = new String("Gaurav");
        p.function(obj);
        String str = new String("and");
        p.function(str);

    }
}
```

My question is why it is invoking `Object` method rather and why not string on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloaded method selection based on the parameter's real type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type)

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why it is invoking Object method rather and why not string on

Because the compiler doesn't know it's a `String` any more.

The compiler decides which overload to invoke, this isn't decided at runtime. You are passing it a reference to an `Object`, so it looks for methods which accept `Object`. It doesn't bother trying to work out if the thing referred to can be some more specific type.

Comment: but the runtime object is of String type and while overriding a method runtime type of object is checked by jvm i thik

Comment: now got this i'm actually **overloading** methods again in child class........                               this is why it's invoking Object type method........... am i right ??????