# Java Generic method overload

Tags: java, generics

I would like to create a method that have different behaviour, based on the the input type. Basically method overloading.
I'm using the method in a other generic class. The method overload falls back onto the base of the generic. Is there a way i can get it to use the final generic class `String` in this case, instead of falling back onto `Object` type.

Is there a better pattern than method overloading, to have different behaviour based on the final type of a generic?

```java
class GenericOverwrite {
    public static void foo(String bar){
        System.out.println("string");
    }

    public static void foo(Object bar){
        System.out.println("object");
    }
}

class Foo <T extends Object> {
    public void basedOnGeneric(T bar){
        GenericOverwrite.foo(bar);
    }
}

class Test{
    void test(){
        var a = new Foo<String>();
        a.basedOnGeneric("I wish this could print string, but uses the object overloaded method");

        var b = new Foo<Object>();
        b.basedOnGeneric("This should print object");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the (actual) problem you have. There are other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type which might be related to your problem.

Comment: side note: **`extends Object`** in `T extends Object` is redundant, as all classes in Java extend (directly or indirectly) `Object`

Comment: You may want to consider using the visitor pattern: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/visitor-design-pattern-java

Comment: This sure is tricky :) The way I understand it is that when the compiler tries to compile `GenericOverwrite.foo(bar)`, all it knows is that `T` (the type of `bar`) is `Object`. So, it selects to compile an invocation to `foo(Object)` every time. It is because the compiler decides which overloaded method to call, not the runtime. And, even though at the specific call site (`new Foo<String>()`) the compiler knows the generic type, it has to compile method `basedOnGeneric` only once, as above - i.e. a call to `foo(Object)`. I feel that you should try the visitor pattern, as mentioned above.

Comment: One idea is if you inside `foo(Object)` can check `bar instanceof String` and delegate if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround the issue by passing the method to the constructor:

```
class Foo <T extends Object> {
    private final Consumer<T> cons;

    Foo(Consumer<T> cons) {
        this.cons = cons;
    }

    public void basedOnGeneric(T bar){
        cons.accept(bar);
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo<String> a = new Foo<String>(GenericOverwrite::foo);
        a.basedOnGeneric("I wish this could print string, but uses the object overloaded method");

        Foo<Object> b = new Foo<Object>(GenericOverwrite::foo);
        b.basedOnGeneric("This should print object");
    }
}
```